# Xamarin Android app crashes with missing google play service classes when Proguard enabled

Tags: android, xamarin, android-proguard, android-multidex

Without making any significant changes to our Xamarin Android app, yesterday our release builds started crashing on app startup:

> Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.R$string"

I suspect this is due to reaching some sort of class number limit. I have the multi-dex option checked in the project settings, and I also have android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" set on the application node in AndroidManifest.xml, so I wouldn't expect to hit any sort of limit.

In any case, since multi-dex support isn't working, my next attempt to get it working was to enable Proguard to optimize the classes that are bundled in the app. I downloaded the latest proguard files (5.3.3) and deployed them to /android/sdk/tools/proguard. I updated the proguard-android.txt file to include the following lines:

```
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

However, when the app starts and it tries to use google location services, it crashes the app:

> Xamarin caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method
>   "Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbym;.getLastLocation(Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient;)Landroid/location/Location;"
>     at
>   md5ecd6d76dd0054fab042915172720bf10.LocationService.n_onConnected(Native
>   Method)   at
>   md5ecd6d76dd0054fab042915172720bf10.LocationService.onConnected(LocationService.java:35)
>     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzad.zzk(Unknown
>   Source:108)

I'm not sure what I'm missing, I thought the keep command above would ensure these classes were still included. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Got it working... I created a proguard.cfg file in the root of my Xamarin project, changed its build action to ProguardConfiguration, and then set its content to:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

I had to save it in TextEdit with UTF8 encoding, otherwise it can't be parsed.

It still doesn't explain why multi-dex support isn't working, but at least we're unblocked now...

Comment: but this usage makes your app bigger i believe because you keep all the classes and members

Comment: beside that you cant simply change it in visual studio? do you have to use like notepad++?